# Calculating the probability of coming out ahead on the game show "The Wall"

Tags: probability

I've been mindlessly watching the NBC game show called "The Wall." in which the contestants can, in theory, become multi-millionaires in under 30 minutes. The show is great fun, but its obvious that the odds of becoming that rich is nearly impossible. I'm curious: how would one calculate the probability the contestant comes out ahead?

Note: I'm going to remove some of the rules that simplifies the outcome and removes some unnecessary variables. Feel free to read the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wall_(game_show)) page if you want to get adventurous.

There are two contestants on the show, and both play together. There are 4 rounds of the game.

---

### Round one: "Free fall"

In this portion, the contestants answer 5 questions, and, based on how well they did, earn a decent chunk of change. The amount of money is put in the bank and this amount becomes the "contract" amount. The "contract" comes back at the end of the game.

1. Four balls drop and each land on a value. Those values are added to the bank.
2. The actor places a ball at a random location on the top of the board (let us not worry about placement effecting the outcome of the value).
3. The brain is asked a multiple choice question.
4. The ball is dropped, and lands on the value.
5. If the brain answers the question correctly, the value is added to the bank. If they answer incorrectly, that amount is subtracted from the bank.
6. Repeat step 2 - 5 two more times
7. Finally, four balls are dropped from the top and the values they land on are subtracted from the bank.

---

### Contestant Decision

At this point, one of the two contestants leave the stage and enter an 'isolation room.' We will call this contestant 'The Brain.' The other contestant stays on stage; I'll call this contestant 'the actor.' The Actor picks places on the board for the ball to drop and decides if a question should be answered by The Brain. The actor also make decisions to play "combos" to multiply the value of an answer, but lets leave those out. The Brain enters the booth knowing the value of the "contract" and must decide at the end of the game to keep the "contract" or rip it up.

---

### Round two: Small bounty

The bank is set to the value from round one.

The board has the following slots at the bottom: 1, 5000, 100, 20000, 10, 10000, 1, 25000, 1, 10000, 10, 20000, 100, 5000, 1

Round operates as so:

1. Two balls drop and each land on a value. Those values are added to the bank.
2. The actor places a ball at a random location on the top of the board (let us not worry about placement effecting the outcome of the value).
3. The brain is asked a multiple choice question.
4. The ball is dropped, and lands on the value.
5. If the brain answers the question correctly, the value is added to the bank. If they answer incorrectly, that amount is subtracted from the bank.
6. Repeat step 2 - 5 two more times
7. Finally, two balls are dropped from the top and the values they land on are subtracted from the bank.

---

### Round three: Big bounty

The bank stays at the output of round two.

The board has the following slots at the bottom: 1, 50000, 100, 100000, 10, 200000, 1, 300000, 1, 400000, 10, 500000, 100, 1000000, 1

Round operates as so:

1. Four balls drop and each land on a value. Those values are added to the bank.
2. The actor places a ball at a random location on the top of the board (let us not worry about placement effecting the outcome of the value).
3. The brain is asked a multiple choice question.
4. The ball is dropped, and lands on the value.
5. If the brain answers the question correctly, the value is added to the bank. If they answer incorrectly, that amount is subtracted from the bank.
6. Repeat step 2 - 5 two more times
7. Finally, four balls are dropped from the top and the values they land on are subtracted from the bank.

---

### Round four: The decision

At this point, the brain does not know the final value of the bank since round one. They must decide, based on how he/she answered the questions, if:

- They sign the contract and take that money home
- They rip up the contract and take home the results after round three (even if that value is $0)

---

My question is: if I was the brain, I only have 3 variables: the value of the contract, the confidence I have answered each of the 3 questions in round 2, and the confidence I have answered each of the 3 questions in round 3. **Is it possible to calculate if it makes more sense to keep the contract, or if I should rip it up in order to maximum my gain?**

Comment: Note: you refer to the contestants as "the brain" and "the actor" before explaining the terminology. An edit may need to be made regarding this.

Comment: what are the slots in round 1 ?